# Use of similarity function and RowMatrix in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, similarity, apache-spark-mllib

I need to compute similarity between average vector computed from RowMatrix and all vectors inside same RowMatrix.

To compute average vector I am doing this (example in Java):

```
RowMatrix matrix = new RowMatrix(vectorOfUserToItems.rdd());
Vector meanVector = matrix.computeColumnSummaryStatistics().mean();
```

How to add this vector into RowMatrix "matrix" so I could compute similarity, or maybe I should do it somehow different?